# Why does the input of the op-amp introduce a DC offset to my signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

I'm interested in measuring the resistance change in a sensor (pk-pk about 1ohm) using an instrumentation amplifier.
I chose to go with a constant current source to get the best possible sensitivity and linearity.

I decided against using a Wheatstone bridge because that would cut the sensitivity in half.
(That's what my simulations and math show, but something about that seems wrong)

The signal of interest is in the ballpark of the audible range.

I simulated the circuit in LT Spice, with and without the Op-amp, and I need some help understanding what the op-amp is doing to my signal. The circuit without the op-amp shows my signal exactly how I want it, zero DC offset. However, when I introduce the op-amp, my signal is shifted down a bit. I can reduce this effect by reducing R1.

What's the cause of the DC offset?

[image: Simulaton]

Comment: Where in node n004 ? It has 0 mV offset.. If n004 is on the topright of your schematic: The offset almost certainly comes from the input bias current of the amplifier. This is essentially a small DC current that flows through R1 and causes a voltage drop.

Comment: @tobalt Perhaps blue on a black background was a bad color choice. n004 is from the circuit on the right. The blue signal (V+) is from the circuit on the right with the op-amp. I understand that the DC offset is caused by a DC current, but why is this DC current not present in the circuit without the op-amp? The Capacitor should block DC, so the DC must be coming from the op-amp.

Comment: What op-amp do you refer to?

Comment: @Andyaka Specifically the AD8429 instrumentation amp, but I suppose this would apply to op-amps in general.

Comment: An InAmp is NOT an op-amp. Please don't confuse them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The offset almost certainly comes from the input bias current of the amplifier. This is essentially a small DC current that flows through R1 and causes a voltage drop.

[image]

If you multiply -25nA with 200kOhm you obtain a prediction for the input offset of 5 mV. So the value you observe is of similar magnitude.

To compensate place a similar resistor in line with IN-.

One should note that the AD8429 is a very low noise amplifier with bipolar input. These things are usually used with input impedances on the order of 10 kOhm and below. So you should consider to make these 200kOhm resistors much smaller.

In addition, the output of the in-amp stage will also amplify the input offset voltage of the in-amp. This value is not visible at your V+ node but can be found in the datasheet to be on order of 100 µV.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks!